# Trouble Setting Up Apache NiFi with HTTPS and Traefik Reverse Proxy in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, https, apache-nifi, traefik

I'm currently attempting to run Apache NiFi in a Docker container with HTTPS enabled, alongside Traefik acting as a reverse proxy. When I run NiFi in unsecure mode, everything works fine. However, when I try to activate HTTPS for secure mode, I encounter issues.

Here's my Docker Compose configuration for running NiFi with HTTPS enabled:

```
nifi:
    image: {{ nifi_docker_image }}
    hostname: nifi
    container_name: nifi
    restart: on-failure 
    environment: 
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_PORT=9443
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - NIFI_WEB_PROXY_HOST={{ nifi_dns }}
      - NIFI_WEB_PROXY_CONTEXT_PATH=/
      - NIFI_WEB_PROXY_PORT=443      
      - SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_USERNAME={{ nifi_admin_username }}
      - SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_PASSWORD={{ nifi_admin_passwrd }}  
      - NIFI_HOME=/opt/nifi/nifi-current
      - NIFI_LOG_DIR=/opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs
      - NIFI_TOOLKIT_HOME=/opt/nifi/nifi-toolkit-current
      - NIFI_PID_DIR=/opt/nifi/nifi-current/run
      - NIFI_BASE_DIR=/opt/nifi
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "https://localhost:9443/health"]
      interval: '30s'
      timeout: '20s'
      retries: 3  
      start_period: '5s'
    volumes:
      - data:/var/data
      - nifi:/opt/nifi
    networks:
      - {{ traefik_network }}
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nifi.rule=Host({{ nifi_dns }}) && PathPrefix(/nifi)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nifi.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nifi.priority=100"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nifi.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nifi.tls.certresolver=le"
      - "traefik.http.services.nifi.loadbalancer.server.port=9443"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nifi.service=nifi"
```

When I try to access NiFi over HTTPS through Traefik, it doesn't seem to work as expected. I've tried accessing NiFi directly over HTTPS without Traefik, and that works fine.

Could you please provide guidance on how to properly configure NiFi with HTTPS and Traefik in Docker to ensure secure access to NiFi with username/password authentication?

Thank you!

Comment: is there any one has the same issue